# Writing a constructor, takes an enum argument from a different class

Tags: java, constructor, enums

I am trying to program an AI for a game and I wanna be able to set different modes for players.

Here is my enum in Type.java:

```
public enum Type {

    Human,Random,Minimax

}
```

And here is the constructor in player.java to set the type of the player:

```
public Player(String name, Type e ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.Type = e;
}
```

Now Eclipse says "Type cannot be resolved or is not a field."
What should I do? Both files are in the same package.

Comment: add Player class code in your question.

Comment: If you are experiencing this Eclipse, there should be an error indication *in the line where the error actually is*. Possibly you can also make use of Eclipse's "quick fix" feature, which might not hit the nail on the head but should give you an idea of where the trouble lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now Eclipse says "Type cannot be resolved or is not a field."

That's telling you that the problem it has is with the `Type` in the line:

```
this.Type = e;
//   ^---- This one
```

Declare a field in `Player` if you haven't already:

```
private Type type;
```

...and then make sure you're using that field's name in the constructor:

```
this.type = e;
```

---

Note I've used lower case for the field name. This is the *overwhelming* convention in Java, and matches what you did with the field `name`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no field Type in your player class.

Something like this would work

```
class Player {

    String name;
    Type e;

    public Player(String name, Type e) {
        this.name = name;
        this.e = e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Main.java:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Player player = new Player( "test", Type.Human );
       System.out.println( player.toString()  );
    }
}
```

Type.java

```
public enum Type {
    Human,  Random, Minimax
 }
```

Player.java

```
public class Player
{
  private String name;
  private Type type;

  public Player(String name, Type e)
  {
     this.name = name;
     this.type = e;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
     return name + " " + type.toString();
  }
}
```

If you compile and run that, toString will return this:

```
test Human
```